# LWC @wire weird variable is null

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
<template if:false={isCM.data}>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-no-row-hover">
      <thead>
        <template for:each={qlisListV.data} for:item="q">
```

part of html page.

```
 @wire(getQuoteLineItemsListVertical, { quoteId: '$recordId', productType: '$productType'})
  qlisListV;

  @wire(isCMCall, {quoteId: '$recordId', productType: '$productType'}) 
  isCM;
```

in JS passing same variable.

isCMCall gets null value for both passed in variables but getQuoteLineItemsListVertical gets correct values eg correct quoteId and productType.

The quoteId and productType were passed in from a flow and lwc is embed in the flow.

Any idea why is that?

Comment: Do you initialize either of these variables to null in your LWC? If you do, make sure you remove this or change to initialize to undefined instead.

Comment: @Ji Zhang Did you import the apex function in Javascript file for isCMCall?

Comment: None of them were initialised as null. Those variables were exported to a flow. so the flow can pass values to those 2 variables. the LWC is embed flow

Comment: Have you tried debugging through your LWC on the browser?

Comment: The flow has those variables set to values before going into LWC step.

Answer (score 1):

```
<template if:false={isCM.data}>
```

Should be:

```
<template if:true={isCM.data}>
```

You don't want to attempt to access the data before it exists.

Comment: I do have another block of code which is rendered when <template if:true={isCM.data}> but it never gets run. So basically if it is true run one block of code, false then run the other block.

Answer (score 1):

It was a horrible mistake. I finally figured it out.

@wire(isCMCall, {quoteId: '$recordId', productType: '$productType'})
isCM;

the apex was using product instead of productType as input parameter name...

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Boolean isCMCall(String quoteId, String product){

but the method is still allowed to be called...